# How can a query be refined to first do a check on another table before performing its main query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query now properly pulling scored matches of like interests between different users given a starting userid.

```
SELECT i2.userid
FROM users_interests i1
INNER JOIN users_interests i2
  ON i2.userid <> i1.userid
  AND i2.interest = i1.interest
WHERE i1.userid = 1
GROUP BY i2.userid
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 0,10;
```

How can I adapt this easily to first do a check for proper country of users in a different `users` table, before running the interest matching query so that it only runs the matching query if they are in the proper country?

The starting `userid` should be '1', and the proper `country` should be '1'

The proper returned result set should be:

```
-------
userid
-------
3
```

Sample test data

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `users` SET `id` = '1', `country` = '1';
INSERT INTO `users` SET `id` = '2', `country` = '2';
INSERT INTO `users` SET `id` = '3', `country` = '1';
INSERT INTO `users` SET `id` = '4', `country` = '4';

CREATE TABLE `users_interests` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `interest` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `users_interests` set `userid` = '1', `interest` = 'term1';
INSERT INTO `users_interests` set `userid` = '1', `interest` = 'term2';
INSERT INTO `users_interests` set `userid` = '1', `interest` = 'term3';
INSERT INTO `users_interests` set `userid` = '1', `interest` = 'term4';
INSERT INTO `users_interests` set `userid` = '2', `interest` = 'term1';
INSERT INTO `users_interests` set `userid` = '2', `interest` = 'term2';
INSERT INTO `users_interests` set `userid` = '2', `interest` = 'term8';
INSERT INTO `users_interests` set `userid` = '2', `interest` = 'term4';
INSERT INTO `users_interests` set `userid` = '3', `interest` = 'term9';
INSERT INTO `users_interests` set `userid` = '3', `interest` = 'term2';
INSERT INTO `users_interests` set `userid` = '3', `interest` = 'term3';
INSERT INTO `users_interests` set `userid` = '3', `interest` = 'term7';
INSERT INTO `users_interests` set `userid` = '4', `interest` = 'term1';
INSERT INTO `users_interests` set `userid` = '4', `interest` = 'term2';
INSERT INTO `users_interests` set `userid` = '4', `interest` = 'term3';
INSERT INTO `users_interests` set `userid` = '4', `interest` = 'term4';
```

Comment: Why do you expect `1` to be in the result?  It's the same as the starting userid and you constrain `i2.userid <> i1.userid`

Comment: You are correct, brainfart, updating question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to deal with 4 tables :

- users u1 : user 1
- users u2 : user 2 (same country as user 1)
- users_interest i1 : interests of user 1
- users_interest i2 : interests of user 2 (same interest as user 1)

Then, you can retrieve common interests and make filters for each table.
The request do what you want :

```
SELECT u2.id, count(*) 
FROM users u1
INNER JOIN users u2
   ON u1.id <> u2.id
  AND u1.country = u2.country
INNER JOIN users_interests i2
   ON i2.userid = u2.userid
  AND i2.interest IN (SELECT interest FROM users_interests
                      WHERE userid = u1.id)
WHERE u1.userid = 1
GROUP BY u2.id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

If you want to retrieve all common interests of all users, you just have to delete the

```
WHERE u1.userid = 1
```

And change :

```
SELECT u1.id sourceid, u2.id targetid, count(*)

GROUP BY u1.id, u2.id
```

Comment: I had to update a couple things, due to my mistyping a field in the test data, but this solution works flawlessly and quickly, thanks, accepting answer.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to join with the `users` table to be able to filter by `country`.  For example:

```
select i2.userid, count(*)
  from users_interests i2 
  join users using (userid)
  join users_interests i1 using (interest)
 where i1.userid <> i2.userid
   and i1.userid = 1
   and country = 1
GROUP BY i2.userid
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC ;
```